# *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xhtml2pdf'*

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a simple Django web site when I compile my code I can get this error:
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xhtml2pdf'*

Comment: It means you either didnt install the xhtml2pdf package or you imported it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here some possible answers.

1- This lib is not correctly installed, try:

```
pip install xhtml2pdf
```

then, check the version if its compatible.

2- Check you python interpreter at the bottom of your IDE.

3- Try creating a virtual enviroment, like this.

```
create a folder
inside this folder, open your command line(cmd)
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
pip install xhtml2pdf
```

Check if any of this works and post the feedback here.